# Maven: missing artifact org.springframework:spring:jar:4.2.6

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a dynamic web project in SpringToolSuite. 
It is converted into a Maven project.

I am getting the issue:

> Mising artifact org.springframework:spring.jar:4.2.6

I already tried to clean, rebuild and run the project. 
It gives:

> Error reading file
>   C:\Users\jublikon.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring\4.2.6\spring-4.2.6.jar
>   C:\Users\jublikon.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring\4.2.6\spring-4.2.6.jar
>   (The system cannot find the specified file)

I do not understand why it is asking for jar files while I am using Maven?

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>HelloWeb</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWeb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\name\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Users\name\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\Users\name\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\name\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\Users\jublikon\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\Users\jublikon\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\Users\jublikon\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\Users\jublikon\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\target</directory>
    <finalName>HelloWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\jublikon\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\jublikon\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\Users\jublikon\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\jublikon\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

I have already seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111408/maven2-missing-artifact-but-jars-are-in-place) but somehow I am not able to solve my problem.

[image]

When I execute

> mvn clean install

in the root directory of the project I get:

```
>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/$%7Bspring.version%7D/spring-framework-bom-$%7Bspring.version%7D.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:${spring.version} in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) @ line 29, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-context:jar is missing. @ line 40, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-core:jar is missing. @ line 44, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-web:jar is missing. @ line 48, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar is missing. @ line 52, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar is missing. @ line 56, column 17
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project HelloWeb:HelloWeb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\jublikon\Development\Spring\Projects\HelloWeb\pom.xml) has 6 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:${spring.version} in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) @ line 29, column 21 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-context:jar is missing. @ line 40, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-core:jar is missing. @ line 44, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-web:jar is missing. @ line 48, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar is missing. @ line 52, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar is missing. @ line 56, column 17
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I have also checked my proxy settings. The active provider in eclipse is set to 'native' and I am not connected through a proxy

In the directory

> ~/.m2/settings.xml

```
main is org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli from plexus.core

set maven.home default ${user.home}/m2

[plexus.core]
optionally ${maven.home}/lib/ext/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/lib/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/conf/logging
```

Comment: There is no `spring.jar` so that will never be found. Since Spring 3.0 only separate modules (spring-beans, spring-context etc.) are available.

Comment: you can use `mvn clean install -X` to track the issue  to get specifics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm quite sure there is no artifact called "spring"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>           <!-- *** spring doesn't *** exist  -->
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Depending on the Spring components you need, you should basically include these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my Spring project, I include the Spring artifacts via a BOM (Bill of Materials):

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- more -->
</dependencies>
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting again the same issue although I am using your code.. I have update my question. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: @jublikon there are some things you can try... first: close `eclipse`, open a command line window, go to project directory (same where `pom.xml` is located) and execute `mvn clean install`. What happens?

Comment: @jublikon second: check your proxy settings in eclipse, and in maven's `~/.m2/settings.xml`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have checked your suggestions and updated my previous post.

Comment: @jublikon there's something wrong in your `pom.xml`. Please show complete `pom.xml` ... I'll update my answer, please look at `<properties>`

Comment: I have updated my pom.xml, so my mistake is the missing header ?

Comment: the error message you've posted shows `Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:${spring.version}` . But the POM you've posted doesn't contain a reference to that... I think you mixed up something... I will follow this topic tomorrow. Have a nice evening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112233/discussion-between-jublikon-and-ulrich).

Comment: Referencing the `spring-framework-bom` artifact with an `import` scope does not work in Maven 2 when you don't have access to Maven Central. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41752289/1743551

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me is that I deleted

`/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring/` directory

and then run `mvn clean install` command in my project.

That way Maven downloaded the real .jar file that was previously I guees not recognized.

Comment: For me deleting ```/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework``` directory and following latter solution by you has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maven by default downloads the required dependencies to your local repository so they can be accesses faster next time. Maybe the dependency is either corrupted, or removed from your local disk? Did you check that C:\Users\jublikon.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring\4.2.6\spring-4.2.6.jar actually exists and is a valid spring jar file?

Comment: I see there two files: spring-4.2.6.jar.lastUpdated and spring-4.2.6.pom.lastUpdated. Is taht 'lastUpdated' file a valid jar file?

Comment: No, so your maven did not fetched the required dependency. Try to run mvn clean install on your project and check if it is downloading any artifacts - if not, you should get an error saying what is the problem. Or take a look at the @Ulrich answer, most probably that is your problem - invalid dependecy description

Comment: I think you have hit on an Eclipse oddity. Delete the  C:\Users\jublikon.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring\4.2.6 directory and run mvn clean install on the project. This will force maven to download the real jar, rather than saying "I tried earlier and it didn't work".

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was I downloaded the jar files from mvnrepository I added them from build path and then I did clean compile install in Maven build and then validate the project and then update the project and the errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

For spring framework, I was using the following dependency in my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But it was giving me the error

> Missing artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE

But when I changed the version to the latest one, the error was removed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

So try using the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of the required .jar files are not available in .m2 repo .

1. Right click the project `->Maven ->project Update` .
2. If you are using `settings.xml` provided in working organization , then remove that `settings.xml` and repeat the step 1.
   when you place the `settings.xml` , it always tries to download the required `.jar` files from the organization repo.